# Jekyll / liquid conditional based on existence of YAML key

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to generate output based on whether a YAML key exists. Given a file in `_data` called `users.yml`:

```yaml
 - name: Paul
   phone: 1234
 - name: John
 - name: George
 - name: Ringo
   phone: 4567
```

I loop through the file (using `for user in site.data.users`, and have tried using:

- `{% if user.phone == blank %} {{ "no phone number listed" }} {% endif %}`
- `{% if user.phone == false %} {{ "no phone number listed" }} {% endif %}`
- `{% if user.phone == empty %} {{ "no phone number listed" }} {% endif %}`

but none of these print "no phone number listed" for the 2 entries without a phone number. Is there a way to do this, or would I need to explicitly include an empty string as the value for `phone` for those users that don't have one?

Answer (score 1):

When there is no key, it evaluates to `nil`, so you should have:

`{% if user.phone == nil %} {{ "no phone number listed" }} {% endif %}`

Or, you can use the opposite check:

`{% unless user.phone %}{{ "no phone number listed" }}{% endunless %}`

Here you can read more about truthy and falsy values in Liquid:
https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/truthy-and-falsy/